# Custom UITableViewCell Height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have made up a few different custom cells in my UITableView in Interface Builder, including each of them having a custom height, larger than the default 44 pixels high.

I then load them up like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier;

    for (int cell = 0; cell <= [tableCellsArray count]; cell++) 
    {
        if ([indexPath row] == cell) 
        {
            CellIdentifier = [tableCellsArray objectAtIndex:cell];
        }
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

They each have a custom class and in the code above I loop through an array which basically holds the associated cell identifiers. However upon running the app, all the cells return the default 44 pixel height.

Without using the delegate method to return my own cell height, is there not something I have missed which might cause this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the delegate method?

Comment: I will if need be, however less code the cleaner and having set the height in IB, it should retain it at runtime, so there must be a way to keep the height without overriding what I did in IB?

Comment: I think you need the delegate to use a non custom cell height. It's not really that much code though, just one method you have to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the height of all of your cells in the definition of the tableView, but to set them individualy you have to use the delegate method.  It's confusing that you can set it in IB but it is for display purposes only and not used at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to implement the following selector and apply the proper logic so that based on your type of custom cell the correct height will be set. Without it the default height of 44 will be used

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return YOUR_WANTED_CELL_HEIGHT;
}
```

Don't think you missed anything else.

Answer (score 0):

In **iOS 8** and above we can use the **Dynamic Table View Cell Height**.

Using this feature **UITableviewCell** get its height from its content and We don't need to write **heightForRowAtIndexPath**

All I have to do in **viewDidLoad()**

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Setup constraint in cell:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Here we can see : when the text increases, **Cell** size also get increase automatically without writing **heightForRowAtIndexPath**